# Clear Formula and keep overwritten value

Tags: excel, vba, range

I do have a document with some formulas retrieving data from other tables. Some of the users were overwriting these formulas with more accurate data. I would like to delete now all the data retrieved from the formulas (so basically I would like to delete the formulas) and only keep the manual entered data.

How could this be done? I just know the other way around :)

Comment: Select the whole range, `Home` / `Find and Select` / `Go To Special`, check `Formulas`, `OK`, hit `Del` button on keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I do need a macro for this, as I have to do it on a frequent basis and copy the preserve the changed information.

Comment: So start the macro recorder and record the above steps. It will be a nice one-liner. Want me to do it for you? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the whole range, Home / Find and Select / Go To Special, check Formulas, OK, hit Del button on keyboard.

If you need the VBA code, this is it:

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23).Select
```

Of course you can omit the `Select` thing, and do whatever you want with it, e.g. clear it:

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23).Clear
```

Or on the whole worksheet:

```
Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23).Clear
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. This is what I was looking for. I was just playing around with the SpecialCells idea.